# Confirming solution to system of differential equations in Mathematica

Tags: differential-equations, simplifying-expressions

I am solving a system of 2 second order linear homogeneous constant coefficient differential equations of the form $x''(t)=ax(t)+by(t),\ \ y''(t)=cx(t)+dy(t)$ and the general solution that Mathematica gives is:

[image]

However I'm trying to use this to confirm a general solution of the form:

$x=[\ ]C_1e^{[\ ]t}+[\ ]C_2e^{[\ ]t}+[\ ]C_3e^{[\ ]t}+[\ ]C_4e^{[\ ]t},\ \ y=[\ ]C_1e^{[\ ]t}+[\ ]C_2e^{[\ ]t}+[\ ]C_3e^{[\ ]t}+[\ ]C_4e^{[\ ]t},$

where $[\ ]$ means a number. Is there any way to confirm my answer/get Mathematica's answer in this form?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe try `Collect[Expand@expr, Exp[_*t]]`, where `expr` is your function of `t`.

Comment: @march, thanks for the response. I tried applying your suggestion, however the output remains unchanged. Perhaps it would help if I showed you the inputs; 

A = {{12,-2},{-2,9}};

Eigenvalues[A]

X[t_] = {x[t], y[t]}; 

system = MapThread[#1==#2 &, {X''[t], A.X[t]}] 
  
sol = DSolve[system, {x, y}, t] 

Collect[Expand@sol, Exp[_*t]]